# Water leak on basement ceiling near chimney

Tags: basement, ceiling, leak

[image]I've been seeing water stains on my basement ceiling after heavy rains and not sure what is causing it.  I have a stucco house and the chimney is directly off the house where the leaks are appearing.  I had a test done previously that determined there is a high level of moisture in the plywood behind the stucco chimney.  Is it possible that water could be coming in through the stucco chimney (there are some cracks on it) and into the basement?  If not, is it possible the water could be coming in through the chimney cap? Just not sure what to focus on to fix this issue.  The roof was replaced last year, but this has been going on for several years so it is not roof related.

Comment: High level of moisture and several years, sounds like some removal of wall covering are in your future.  The cracks are a probable source of leaks, but with time some damage(rot, mold) might have happen inside the wall/ceiling.

Comment: Is the chimney cap cracked? If so, fix it and see if the leak stops. Also check to see that the caulking around the cap is still good. Some pictures of the chimney and cap may help you get a good answer.

Comment: The cap doesn't appear cracked.  Not sure about the caulking.  I couldn't see any caulk around the cap. I can only post one picture it seems so I included a picture of the side of the chimney.  Not sure how helpful it is.  I did try to seal some of the cracks previously, but not sure how much that helped.

Comment: Water is really **really** good at entering one place, trickling along unnoticed some great distance, and then dribbling out somewhere else.  I'd start by checking & maybe resealing the top of the chimney where it meets the roof.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll look into that.

Comment: it may be leaking through the roof, where the roof meets the chimney, and running down the inside of the wall into the basement ceiling.